# Android - Maps - My location button not working and blue dot is not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-maps

Just right after I accept request permission location ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION the location button is showing but not working.
I've just pushed it but nothing happens.
Where is the blue dot??

In the other hand, when I restart the app the button is working properly.

This is my code just after permissions has ben accepted:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);   
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

[image]

Comment: on what device do you check it?

Comment: @VadimEksler simulator

Comment: and you see default location on simulator settings?

Comment: if you make click on location button it not shows?

Comment: it can be that blue dot on map, just not in zoom zone that you search?

Comment: @VadimEksler When i push the button nothing happens.

Comment: try to make `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()` and check if you have location

Comment: if in `.addOnCompleteListener()` your `task.getResult() == null` your device dont have location and you need to create `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates()`

Comment: Having the same problem with same configurations

Answer (score 2):

try to set

`googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);`

after accepting the permissions

Comment: That's exactly what  I have right now. You can check the question again.